# Accessing optional parameters in Spring Boot GraphQL

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-graphql

I have this QueryMapping method where I have some parameters marked as required in my GrapthQL schema, but not all. Using `@Argument` allows me to grab all required parameters, but when I send a Query without an optional parameter it crashes. Using the `RequestParam` annotation with a default value doesn't work since its type is an integer and the annotation requires a string. (I guess it's supposed to be called within a REST-API)

```
@QueryMapping
public List<Record> getRecord(Argument String email, @Argument int dateFrom, @RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = 0) int dateTo) {
    return repository.findSpecific(email, dateFrom);
}
```

Edit: Method overloading does not work.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by using Kotlin: Adding a Question mark behind the Parameter Type allows me to set the value to null.